# Is mandatory to have Youtube app installed to use Youtube api

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-developer-api

I was reading several tutorials about how to use the Youtube Api. Just to find out after I implemented it. That it was not working when the original Youtube App was not installed on device. In the tutorials I read this was not mentioned. Just in original doc's it says:

> The API client library interacts with a service that is distributed as a part of the YouTube app for the Android platform

If that is the case I think it is an exclusion criterion. Cause it forces the user to install another 20mb sized app.

So my question would be if there is another way to play youtube Videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use HTML5 player in a web-view. But It may have compatibility issues with older android OS and experience may vary from device to device.